# How to bind a Dep property within DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, list, binding, user-controls, datagridtextcolumn

How can I bind a List Property inside DataGridTextColumn to bind a list from main window.

For this I use

```
public class DataGridListBoxColumn : DataGridTextColumn
    {
        TextBlock tx = new TextBlock();

        public DataGridListBoxColumn()
        {
            tx.Name = "TxB";
        }
        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, Object dataItem)
        {
            Binding b = new Binding();
            b.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridListBoxColumn), 1);
            b.Path = new PropertyPath("ListItem");
            tx.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
            return cell;
        }
        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var x = ListItem;
            Debugger.Break(); //here x is null 
        }

        public List<Student> ListItem
        {
            get { return (List<Student>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly  DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListItem", typeof(List<Student>), typeof(DataGridListBoxColumn));

    }
```

I use TextBlock as hidden for binding purpose only.

How to pass a list binding to DataGridTextColumn?

Comment: Why are you using DataGridTextColumn?  DataGridTemplateColumn with a suitable DataTemplate is the approach that seems best to me.  Otherwise use a converter on the list binding.

Comment: ok  suppose if i change to DataGridTemplateColumn then also how can i get list inside my column

Comment: You don't need to create a custom colum type. Use a DataGridTemplateColumn with a CellTemplate containing an ItemsControl that binds to an IEnumerable of your data objects.

Comment: There are any number of ways to do this.  What is not clear is what you want.  Do you want a single row containing the entire list from the main window?  So if the list is 5 items then the cell is 5 lines high?  What if the list has 100 items?  Do you want to match one item of the list to one row of the table?  To get a decent answer you need to provide a clear example.  The code you have provided is muddled and does provide many clues.  Provide the data.  Explain why you want to do this.